# Migrating all my third party repositories sources.list to deb822-style

Tags: apt

With apt-key getting depreciated and so /etc/apt/trusted.gpg, I decided to change all my repositories to the next thing that I don't have to touch. I don't want to put the files in trusted.gpg.d, since according to the manual it is reserved for packages uses. So, how do I go creating my deb822 source files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend using a single file for both the repository definition and the concomitant public key. This requires apt to be version 2.3.10 or later. That means the only directory where new files will reside is the sources.list.d/. The deb822 format has the same information that the single line has, but in a key: value format, like YALM. The following is an example using Spotify's Debian repository:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

becomes

```
Enabled: Yes
Types: deb
URIs: http://repository.spotify.com
Suites: stable
Components: non-free
Signed-By:
 -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
 .
 mQINBGF5YIABEACnop+0P287u+2dzExoGpe109KHHd1eaj/ULDQZz0A47qJYaOld
 pGqsRq6EUbzrVxGaAsSDfCwlQ4hutP9uH0ekdIr+/te6pbrYYiUvAUthibbq0mm7
 zhpIa8saXLLyImygrPgZpfY3X8l4uWG33hMeU7OHOfReZzycfVxAzENlkomejP+W
 wvzliqz+TYWO7esh730hud0tFYzQjmRtL3UGIFI5sCJkR1NzMqHup/PW4BYM1zZu
 vXPGqyCLaoPV8WQz2Uq5DnX+wmTi2+s/42XbMGzyJVqXx8tjMBQlRHFpvjV1FfYc
 s7niQRnwz6wAZTitIgBYBPAPbGEIE2bi+Njur/z9ys3/Zp5CZOpKkF7TzW39tgvN
 ITq7oTO8DszCfVNrWARBOrWPy3NuAA9xvH1BWdZ7iaVP5UcAaHPG5rg3QGBGJ1HE
 UDYBDnr5GNlBvuv53MqwaThGRAwNyajO78JYuOFfz+DkvgJg9tMITThG3gpfek9Z
 TyHdN1/xZKQziMXNEgcx5CLJMoUCEMiAMKOB+Tng9HQzeCbOLTgugfzGrg2lRTnB
 Vy9o9SxuVBc5nCR1LbfpeDv+MVduYM6aZAFBHA0h8bc5svCMYHyyrfaigb75c/4q
 tg/Lg8GIhStw1za0bdxF8N6yPZvWztQfoQqTnTpldxLc4gkYjYE4IVKfowARAQAB
 tDdTcG90aWZ5IFB1YmxpYyBSZXBvc2l0b3J5IFNpZ25pbmcgS2V5IDx0dXhAc3Bv
 dGlmeS5jb20+iQJUBBMBCAA+FiEE+aIRl27WYvAOWTYeXjxF17MSxkMFAmF5YIAC
 GwMFCQJRQwAFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQXjxF17MSxkOYbQ//
 VgFX2fJTUPAPR4oa79DJi0255lXhv6ZXDW/Yv6W4ycu1iIEXbDYNqBqhL1zwdphk
 Pg49LC0NkVWP3/n5WvbmJP7gfyl344ZPVeaz23ISFM8J9WlxuBonA/KSw7OCkf1+
 b+TxDb8An29hMAknwAQnLZGCoEroe3BPn9qmpbIBkkoRHFWCOAjdY98Arbq19s2k
 68wSeiGS+DcCvDOhnPxbf8M16cew/LDFpFAmbT7HhaFwN4VTLTa4gA3X9csGXMts
 jBqgk2NggoYu1ZF5P3Vt0HzqjaSlLgFe3c+HEZELPMES/zRtxO1VJv5cA9CjYu3c
 ldRlLdY35Y3CeEVzfqq6D8G1av1zpNDXjBk6zr9ZPeu1k5zOpxN008CshF82MZDd
 ymhbb/LMoY4OR1UwFPA8DwJGUE2Nb0PBrAKxpSQFuxM/iQsw1r362ZM6O3Kwyu3Y
 pCEKlbuYKKBnsBRwLY1KjhXh9ngqjxSoudwZSUtpRXp7O9SoFvUgdYsCRJuSrq/2
 qYkYgkXb9XaX1nh52tYPt50mNlceybVaKb5lDoBE6clWlBKasPAyLvjxV5RrBAKf
 adxHn0judK6HunANmZbMV4fkO7MhtyletK88dWKKgtLkVTSnoXz0xYe04LPUHDo+
 VhHeq7s/LpSTlMRs/WeB/Arue2+XuXfVEVdtDi7Mg/Q=
 =GrS9
 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The signed-by public key requires a single space prefix to be recognized as part of the above, otherwise unrecognized lines will be ignored. Make sure the key is ASCII armored. If you have an unarmorred one, just use `gpg --keyring=/public/key.gpg --armor --export <fingerprint>`. If you already added them to your trusted.gpg, export it like so `gpg --keyring=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg --export --armor 177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8`, afterwards delete them using `sudo gpg --keyring=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg --delete-keys 177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8`.

I deliberately put the stanzas in the same order you are used to. If you have arch options in the one line style, you must use "Architectures:" to define them. All stanzas that end in plural accepts several elements. You could add more uris or suites, as long as all are signed with the defined public key.

Comment: Not only do all the lines of the ascii key in the Signed-By clause need to be indented one space, any blank lines (and this is probably only the first line after the "-----BEGIN..." header) needs to be represented as a '.' [dot] character. So that one line becomes ^[space][dot] by itself.seen in the example above.