# "Invalid value set for option Signed-By regarding source ... not a fingerprint"

Tags: apt

I was trying to install Brave Browser on a Linux Mint system and used the echo command from [their website](https://brave.com/linux/#release-channel-installation) and now I can't do anything to fix this, synaptic is broken with this error

```
E: Invalid value set for option Signed-By regarding source https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable (not a fingerprint)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo-apt install`, it all gives me this Signed-By error

Answer (score 2):

The file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list must be removed. If you are actually going to do this, I recommend instead creating [a source file (deb882)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/699355/41104) rather than a list file.

The file contents could be (download and update the Signed-By field downloading the public gpg key contents)

```
Enabled: Yes
Types: deb
URIs: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/
Suites: stable
Components: main
Architectures: amd64
Signed-By:
 -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
 
 mQINBFvFEDIBEADwix8cI/QMI36OjLMpL/2xX4D4JYHZdqwja8xRRoQ7lnw2w+zv
 GnyksvyL6ycEWVw06awzUq+q2/YYNMpWg3zGwuELLytMLMjZ/Y2A57ArA+JH+1b2
 upKiOnvzStTsoh2Tpt3ob4AHlgua37ZqtrLaFjzlQGVuTA2aqA6kWsJuLBPy4Zke
 yl1i3JwfAjNfhQDYpniwG6a4wEui8GQJX5GvBGtctLU+aHflSFqvoLtRP2UVDApE
 UaoqK/oil54mEUpQBkD7S619GQLNh1PWnHwlO0K2fGGZxiIY8RpplN4GgSSzFZ11
 BQE3DzaXL8E7O1+dIBnuAdaMVheWAH23mRIrUCKOpaYJGy4JLhhfrjPo34F+8ruK
 k57cFHgZMc/N2il2eXYtMrgPKCJCNAr3XBhiVDj0x+InSwK19V/fjTSUJsM+Ru18
 NgL4+XeeBJHCDWOG9b4Z/94+d0KBwDuxyY4TIFgZ817dUXxM4RKh8IIWaIufgWcT
 CbB6aYZGdCBn8trSisIdCfMdhL4bUQ/AzfO0EygQ7PonFN5EUSpfV8EGbCjt6MVq
 nPUdiVndC6PgKwg5ox8ZOlHhXCtZsqZc8Qq5JT3j1RVKVHc/HqwJhRI529/EOp3N
 7Pfl6FbjqlVzQM97cUIOZUvzPIG9Y6qDoT54pKltGV5OqmeOEuPzmslwIQARAQAB
 tCJCcmF2ZSBTb2Z0d2FyZSA8c3VwcG9ydEBicmF2ZS5jb20+iQJUBBMBCAA+AhsD
 BQsJCAcCBhUICQoLAgQWAgMBAh4BAheAFiEE2LrU3n7hevUqg0stC7dYKcLU6CEF
 AmKFME8FCQxjup0ACgkQC7dYKcLU6CGcuA//XWQsmD8bqy1vBcMAFwXd4chlVhIU
 NJ0Jn4rspN/z9hj26GF3gYtzcsRVWcUslxQm2qns3Nd3oo49COdesXWyQIcipUDy
 393c+8GFMEvB77FmvcXJ0aqx9rpOsk2e9of5am+fi6pXpid//Ob9jT9QYfwaTbdP
 HX1Sx7bEAvjMGc1tCQEVtlf7oXgnAAjST+rXC5DHHT9mkk/aKtr/Pd7VGQ5VeiId
 NUHpdsin/5P6upXkwopE3MHtne5kdLXCyP5DzCxiPvuoQPdzMTkWgm0ipUutwxDk
 EXVsimntYubCA8lnq2sDz6WV4cFwMaSbIeaoxkGvl7VSdBnZUXChUEQ+XVfEy3LF
 K69xQP5P10RngE/jjCd8C/ZIuBAtxqvSUk8pKxb7V0m0mboYejRNwhZZwKC6nE/g
 Os5iwx4JEUiVzJOMLfbZkKFk3hiQavtZWC4SrmSxWFKXArA7qwwSVRIZt/dT2+1+
 JrMWJ842vkR87sWXGjrW0mef9EpM34LgwRyoFGhgnR+65KHodKrNh4XVR3InRSsK
 tloyvMnIxLbohsSb+Q0lYtAUycvK88A4CPmtkNvAKo6cuxMBQsQVxXIowWB40q+e
 gHvZhXS7f89kmZM1bmf9ifUqkfeMWjhdad/5OQq/eak5QQFTXS6ROfTqGW2g9a9y
 skSrzh/ZBepZJLW5Ag0EXai0nAEQAMt19Vv96p6Qp2Oo6h0axShUqqYhHLe/HzHU
 QJwoggirU4e6CNH1D8de/6/Wy/QsbGVyYpsxliog7sNbGXp4T8UowY8dHDN4z+7+
 6MSSthYrs/zlyml/shDvCFuve6LpZuOCVlOruax+v3NbaDoQDQYEKDku3ggv7J1G
 IP+LbIGvzVe62Q/Bqrgblnr+NByaWHAyNbo1v/GfLcp2Ltxn6j0bmVY4I3uYi1Au
 xeo5KbCBwh0FZTDMbO8t+H5cSuNsqoN/EZcELGabiRysKt7z9YVNkyyhZZp5v3QP
 DlhhAb4+T8g2fll/JXMUdcR3WGkwOBf94XOdIVvRUoiCXeW+iOsZ70onJGVHxwXg
 awfGmm73KfwD5c8YHrOYTSUkIaAhB+czkMNPoSQ7f4sTaROyu/Rnv2s27cHxg570
 LGbVyGboEQK60y/gWRYTmS3+/YfOFn7vrNdWCcDUOKrDgl4lXSeQ76sTLOG7P+sU
 OlrUh/eUAkxANrvzfY59U2xsqxBhfcm3/zBHfvXv44h15uoqfukxZudq35knTWMq
 N/x97h9hQ26vVsjX8UzcDCjJ5KzrSKLE1Qtu3t5gD10Rue7kk4iCsXwvrYPQIcEa
 Yi3hzW+rjCxkGcaGpZtS0JuMoTgxoUA1s9XOu916sF2vuMdnPipx8/OsaYUEVQCd
 sPwlAUOdABEBAAGJBHIEGAEKACYCGwIWIQTYutTefuF69SqDSy0Lt1gpwtToIQUC
 YoUwYQUJCJ7ixQJAwXQgBBkBCgAdFiEEm9GYothIxILjVQaXqFgL3ILT3GwFAl2o
 tJwACgkQqFgL3ILT3Gxz+RAAl7EichPIEFgk9JmenhwGWPxRF59NEWExluAGY/wi
 yfqLg7SVxowNrZOSdUgxZvKqEoAarsFtdmnG5mrIOMCd3MmJvm2EVbQbDFGF2ojR
 paP2NefO5Au5nHqu0j0TM0NelSukGOK66MAuzu2SWKMNArfuKoBEXbaS57uVf0+t
 /kg9z4ga9mwBOyXfCi9eceAbrY/oJaXjGHoZk5hnShL8m0I9cHnG044Kps8/8lQ8
 R5ELcdb5b8xYfR4oVIT2t/QmvTE8AhibO9//+MCHejWSF3K3EsF7Dwr8INCO+ATh
 YZNYth1szpVNkcd4FyYj956wRD3vAzrpV7lzwyTJ6jsa/L6fYELhrA+b2m90kT3F
 8+PUe/jglyjnfFShDrglb4X2RP3AkYSQLkCl5Bk4sB79wTNUJ0GZp7ZLlHfddIa3
 bPwZhtLN1xop0emxvHy0xc5MiOJiDLT6BpqaPomSUVIrw/WUt7zwKwbOA9qD5WFM
 irX6H5lmSkYj8gtTEqQXn2JUridyYqoJeQldCDPql/LEC2rdInld1dBrd+maVjau
 Rvx5m4B7LCbWLtEOAfSDGxYU5Sj3LM8X6z/p3TMwBZvp44d8VkkI9NFqutInaLE6
 iMwWVqD3uSp5WeWom9iTENfHzpMC7q1eOckRb+PZdTLJ4BUys++iYCTnjHEFBI2r
 iSAJEAu3WCnC1Oghes0P/RrkrXpwvD5iDbKDbzH4ie70XRvuRlmfWnjuFeZg3sJM
 y7xSlVYtjleoBd4YMnFE65pNFu3Pr73JblcUuNHw+49cD8PtdRpz81jQhcC4iOPj
 nYY6/ke1JvkW3UP7GIQEKs/+rKqEedigYihZcjFKjBL9VJDAvnjYqc5Fp96XMet2
 +xB5lgOVWSW9/fqrBBisQnMFtPuLEg5Aq8EmVNwLyRSDaQE/UJWz9Ft2SStV/GFB
 1Qy50h0cVVKouNSq10ixKKP0xpWCaXXs4l4qfeIu5R8MdCLN3ZMhfe2lM4Hn/bWV
 w4gKsTEePXAOAeeqO9Q7SffHyxYSg/Op+UKMqpfzFLwgLE4QxagZRKl45i9G5g4o
 3v1uRX/6eBHvHWhTV+N2Hql5OORUoXldUP5XzM2MjevUK8eXGc78H0EDQ65yVVI3
 uKPeCvnkZsMqb2e+f7GmkgOY3bMFO5/G47RVyoLSYA0L/i+b8d5O8Zu47FGoLHHO
 rkSqFU9RmF6IliSsINuaX4uU0/6I77d4ojtgSMO7QvjSYrQiVuyXZ32HUxEdIjRq
 HCFtO6cyo5UfrqBoQO2WrG55AK9yLKeMtGE7Q1u6sjhiv5fT8+PQMBVVhPXI7BqS
 vZoEJOL/NWjZo/VGJepx32tf17Ovnd3YWUbxsJnJQGZpULe1yBm8znIsSV91dubF
 =S8EC
 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Note the whitespace before each line of the public key.